# Return data from mongoDB nested queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

What is the method to return data from nested queries.

Im merging multiple function calls into one single module , 
I have the following code

```
  retrieveStudentSessions: function(req, res, callback){
     MongoClient.connect(config.mongoPath+config.dbName, function(err, db) {
       if(err){
         return callback(new Error("Unable to Connect to DB"));
       }
      var collection        = db.collection(config.userList);
      var sessionCollection = db.collection(config.session);
      var templateCollection = db.collection(config.template);
      var tempSession  = {session:[], templates:[]};

      //Obtain UserID
      collection.find({'email' : req.user['_json'].email}).nextObject(function(err, doc) {
          if(err){
                return callback(new Error("Error finding user in DB"));
          } 
          //Search Session collection for userID
            sessionCollection.find({ $or : [{'studentsB' : doc['userid']},{'studentsA' : doc['userid']}]}).each(function(err, doc) {
              if(err){
                  return callback(new Error("Error finding user in DB"));
              }  
                  //Update JSON
                  tempSession.session.push(doc);
                  //Query for Template Title using Template ID from Session Collection
                  templateCollection.find({'_id' : doc['templateId']}).nextObject(function(err, doc){
                    if(err){
                          return callback(new Error("Error finding user in DB"));
                    } 
                    //Update JSON
                    tempSession.templates.push(doc);
                  });
            });
        return callback(null, tempSession);
      });
    });
  }
```

Caller Function

```
dbCall.retrieveStudentSessions(req, res, function(err, result){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                    return;
                }
                console.log(result);
            });
```

Above code returns error `undefined is not a function` when i try to return variable `tempSession`. The same works fine with single queries . Is there any specific method of return, when it comes to nested queries?

Comment: What is the callback here?  This looks like a request handler?

Comment: Do you get a stack trace with that error? If so, where does it point to? Also, your code should be using something like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async), because you're calling the callback before `sessionCollection.find().each()` has finished.

Comment: The error always points to `return callback(null, tempSession);`. Ive tried to use the callback after sessionCollectionfind and also after templateSessionCollection. The data is generated correct. But when the return statement is included, `undefined is not a function` pops up.